# regexp-opt function missing in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've started playing around with elisp to create font-locks (syntax highlighting) in Emacs. Most of the tutorials out there mention using an elisp function "regexp-opt" to optimize regular expressions, but my version of emacs (23.2) doesn't seem to have that function. Furthermore, Googling for the answer doesn't seem to turn up useful results. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I am running emacs 23.2 and I have the function.

Answer (score 6):

As you can find out via `C-h f regexp-opt`:

> regexp-opt is a compiled Lisp
>   function.
>
> (regexp-opt strings &optional paren)
>
> Return a regexp to match a string in
>   the list strings. Each string should
>   be unique in strings and should not
>   contain any regexps, quoted or not. 
>   If optional paren is non-nil, ensure
>   that the returned regexp is enclosed
>   by at least one regexp grouping
>   construct. The returned regexp is
>   typically more efficient than the
>   equivalent regexp:
>
> (let ((open (if paren "\(" ""))
>   (close (if paren "\)" "")))
>   (concat open (mapconcat 'regexp-quote
>   strings "\|") close))
>
> If paren is `words', then the
>   resulting regexp is additionally
>   surrounded by \< and >.

Note, that it is a function to be used in Lisp code, not an interactive command which you could run with `M-x`

Answer (score 5):

regexexp-opt is a elisp function but not an emacs command.  That is why you cannot execute it by running: M-x regexp-opt

However, you can execute any elisp function from the elisp shell.  Type in M-x eshell.  And from this shell you can run regexp-opt

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `regexp-opt` is not a command (so you cannot invoke it using `M-x`).  But you can invoke an application of it interactively, using `M-:`.

For example, `M-: (regexp-opt '("foo" "toto" "blat" "total" "mistral")) RET` returns the regexp `"\\(?:blat\\|foo\\|mistral\\|tot\\(?:al\\|o\\)\\)"`.